# SSO callback configuration

Tags: oracle-apex

I would like to setup SSO in apex using Social Signin. Part of the app registration in SSO provider is also [redirect URI] which should be set as ....

```
 https://apex.mycompany.com/ords/apex_authentication.callback
 https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/apex_authentication.callback
```

unfortunately this address "apex_authentication.callback" does not exist currently on our apex server.

Is this some kind of generic page which should be somehow switch ON, or it should be implemented myself?

Answer (score 1):

apex_authentication is only public synonym for package wwv_flow_authentication_api where is defined function get_callback_url() which return callback url with parameters

select APEX_AUTHENTICATION.GET_CALLBACK_URL () from dual;

http://my.host.com:8080/pls/apex/apex_authentication.callback?p_session_id=9332345578758&p_app_id=2&p_ajax_identifier=hkcP8g-YUHd49DlIRQJAVYXyOJByibKhf7U123123M&p_page_id=123

the url is working ONLY in case that the parameters are part of the URL, otherwise it return 404!